# Cmake cannot find dependent library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build the library https://github.com/mosra/magnum, which depends on a project https://github.com/mosra/corrade on windows.

I am following the installation instruction, first, i build the corrade library by going into corrade/build/ and running cmake ..

Then, I go into the magnum/build directory and run cmake ..

But I get an

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-     3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find Corrade (missing: CORRADE_INCLUDE_DIR
_CORRADE_CONFIGURE_FILE)
```

I tried setting the CORRADE_INCLUDE_DIR env variable, but that did not work.  I also tried moving the corrade library into the magnum/modules/ folder, but still to no avail.

I am fairly new to cmake, and have been attempting to fix this for a while.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may have to look at the source for the finder for Corrade to see why it can't find the CORRADE_INCLUDE_DIR given the CORRADE_INCLUDE_DIR you entered. If you entered a path using \ as the path separator can you try using / as the path separator instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering.  I opened up the FindCorrade.cmake file, and found these two lines.

    find_path(CORRADE_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES Corrade/Corrade.h)

I found that it's using the forward slash operator, I set the CORRADE_INCLUDE_DIR as the direct path to the Corrade folder, still to no avail

Comment: The build of Magnum tries to search for Corrade lib from your Windows system path and Windows registry. In your build of Corrade, if you just run cmake .., this library would not appear in system path or Windows registry. I know in Unix system, after "cmake ..", we should continue to run "make" and "make install" to really install this library to system path, so that cmake can find this library. Windows system may have a different way.